# Grails: Unit testing controller method with domain class

Tags: unit-testing, grails, grails-domain-class, grails-controller

I have a simple grails controller:

```
class AuthorController {

    def index(){
       def authors = Author.findByFirstName("Albert")
       render (view: "author-page", model: ["authors":authors])

   }
}
```

Here, Author is a domain class that maps to a table in SQL database.

I am trying to write a unit test for it like this:

```
import grails.test.mixin.Mock

@Mock(Author)
class AuthorControllerSpec extends Specification {

    void "when index is called, authorPage view is rendered"() {
          when:
               controller.index()
          then:
               view == "/author-page"

    }
```

}

But when I run this test, I keep getting java.lang.IllegalStateException: Method on class [com.mypackage.Author] was used outside of a Grails application. If running in the context of a test using the mocking API or bootstrap Grails correctly.

Can someone tell me how to properly test my action? I am having trouble mocking that Author.findByFirstName() method.

I am using Grails 2.4.2

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import grails.test.mixin.Mock
import grails.test.mixin.TestFor
import spock.lang.Specification

@TestFor(AuthorController)
@Mock([Author])
class AuthorControllerSpec extends Specification {

    void "when index is called, authorPage view is rendered"() {
          when:
               controller.index()
          then:
               view == "/author-page"

    }    
}
```

Try this.

Answer (score 0):

Use `@TestFor(AuthorController)` annotation at the top in your controller test case. Also the brackets must not be there after extending `Specification` class. Just wanted to confirm, it might be typo in the question. If the problem still persist, try installing Grails [webxml](http://grails.org/plugin/webxml) plugin.

Look at [here](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/testing.html#unitTestingControllers) for more info.

Hope that helps!

Thanks,
SA

Comment: Thanks. I am using @TestFor at the top, still does not work. The brackets aren't there. Thanks for catching that. I have removed it.